# How Do I Format Ransak Params When Writing a Minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, minitest, ransack

### Edit

There were 2 issues preventing my test from passing:

1. I forgot that 3 clubs (not 2) in my setup contained the letter 'b'.
2. My clubs.yml fixture contained a block that created 100 additional clubs. Since I'm using will_paginate, not all the clubs appear on 1 result page.

For the record, the following syntax worked.

```
get clubs_path, params: { q: { name_cont: "at" } }
```

### Original Question

I'm writing an [Minitest](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#rails-meets-minitest) for my search queries, but don't know how to format the **params**

Below is a Minitest I wrote that is failing, when it should be passing. When I actually test my app in the browser, is works as expected, and searches against the name. I think the issues has to do with how I am passing in the **params**.

**Failing Minitest**

```
# name search
test "should display correct clubs on name search" do
  # go to search page
  get clubs_path
  assert_template 'clubs/index'
  # search for "b"
  get clubs_path, params: { "q[name_cont]" => 'b' }
  assert_template 'clubs/index'
  # ensure all clubs with "b" in their name appear
  assert_select "a[href=?]", club_path(@quincy), count: 0
  assert_select "a[href=?]", club_path(@worcester), count: 0
  assert_select "a[href=?]", club_path(@brtc), count: 1
  assert_select "a[href=?]", club_path(@baa), count: 1
end
```

**Controller**

```
def index
  # if there is data in origin field
  if params[:origin].present? && params[:distance].present?
    @q = Club.near(params[:origin], params[:distance], order: :location).order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page]).ransack(params[:q])
    @clubs = @q.result(distinct: true)
  # if there isn't data in the origin and distance fields. show everything
  else
    @q = Club.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page]).ransack(params[:q])
    @clubs = @q.result(distinct: true)
  end
end
```

**Search Form**

```
<%= search_form_for @q, url: yield(:search_path) do |f| %>
  ...
  <div class="form-group"><!-- name -->
    <%= f.label :name_cont %>
    <%= f.search_field :name_cont, class: "form-control" %>
  </div><!--/ name -->
  ...
<% end %>
```

I've also tried the following, but still no luck.

```
get clubs_path, params: { q: { name_cont: "b" } }
get clubs_path, q: { name_cont: 'b'}
```

Oddly enough, the minitest below is working. I'm not sure if this is the preferred way to write the params, but the test did pass.

```
get clubs_path, params: { "q[club_categories_id_eq_any][]" => @road_racing.id, distance: 10, origin: "02169" }
```

**Working Minitest**

```
# category search
test "should display correct clubs on category search" do
  # go to search page
  get clubs_path
  # ensure page loads
  assert_template "clubs/index"

  # fill out form with quincy proximity, searching for road_racing
  get clubs_path, params: { "q[club_categories_id_eq_any][]" => @road_racing.id, distance: 10, origin: "02169" }
  # ensure quincy is the only club
  assert_select "a[href=?]", club_path(@quincy), count: 1
  assert_select "a[href=?]", club_path(@worcester), count: 0
end
```

Comment: can you temporarily configure your initializers/ransack.rb to have `config.ignore_unknown_conditions = false` [see docs](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Configuration) so that we can verify if indeed there is no problem with the predicate `name_cont`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I made this configuration. The test still fails, and the web app still works as designed. Any thoughts?